# convertir formulario ipn paypal php a laravel

Tags: php, laravel

tengo un código de ejemplo sobre ipn(paypal) que esta en php. que me funciona correctamente pero quisiera implementarlo dentro de un controlador de laravel y no lo consigo. ya que "NO" tengo muchos conocimientos de programación.

la ruta del ipn ejemplo: test.com/ipn/paypal

entonces lo que hago es crear una ruta:

```
Route::post('/ipn/paypal', ['uses' => 'PaypalController@ipn', 'as' => 'paypal.ipn']);
```

Después creo el controlador PaypalController.php con la function (ipn)

```
public function ipn(Request $request)
{
    define("DEBUG", 0);
    define("USE_SANDBOX", 1);

    $request        = json_decode($request->getContent(), true);
    $raw_post_array = explode('&', $request);
    $myPost         = array();

    foreach ($raw_post_array as $keyval) {
        $keyval = explode('=', $keyval);
        if (count($keyval) == 2) {
            $myPost[$keyval[0]] = urldecode($keyval[1]);
        }

    }

    $req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';

    if (function_exists('get_magic_quotes_gpc')) {
        $get_magic_quotes_exists = true;
    }

    foreach ($myPost as $key => $value) {
        if ($get_magic_quotes_exists == true && get_magic_quotes_gpc() == 1) {
            $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));
        } else {
            $value = urlencode($value);
        }
        $req .= "&$key=$value";
    }

    if (USE_SANDBOX == true) {
        $paypal_url = "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr";
    } else {
        $paypal_url = "https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr";
    }

    $ch = curl_init($paypal_url);

    if ($ch == false) {
        return false;
    }

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $req);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, 1);

    if (DEBUG == true) {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, 1);
    }

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Connection: Close'));

    $res = curl_exec($ch);

    if (curl_errno($ch) != 0) // cURL error
    {
        if (DEBUG == true) {
            error_log(date('[Y-m-d H:i e] ') . "No se puede conectar a PayPal para validar el IPN: " . curl_error($ch) . PHP_EOL, 3, LOG_FILE);
        }
        curl_close($ch);
        exit;
    } else {
        if (DEBUG == true) {
            error_log(date('[Y-m-d H:i e] ') . "HTTP respuesta:" . curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT) . " para IPN: $req" . PHP_EOL, 3, LOG_FILE);
            error_log(date('[Y-m-d H:i e] ') . "HTTP respuesta a la validacion: $res" . PHP_EOL, 3, LOG_FILE);
        }
        curl_close($ch);
    }
}
```

pero cuando hago el test de https://developer.paypal.com/developer/ipnSimulator/
no logra conectar y no se que hacer. ya que si creo un test de ipn a "test.com/ipn/paypal.php"

(paypal.php)

```
define("DEBUG", 0);
define("USE_SANDBOX", 1);
define("LOG_FILE", "resultadopaypal.txt");

$raw_post_data  = file_get_contents('php://input');
$raw_post_array = explode('&', $raw_post_data);
$myPost         = array();

foreach ($raw_post_array as $keyval) {
    $keyval = explode('=', $keyval);
    if (count($keyval) == 2) {
        $myPost[$keyval[0]] = urldecode($keyval[1]);
    }

}

$req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';

if (function_exists('get_magic_quotes_gpc')) {
    $get_magic_quotes_exists = true;
}

foreach ($myPost as $key => $value) {
    if ($get_magic_quotes_exists == true && get_magic_quotes_gpc() == 1) {
        $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));
    } else {
        $value = urlencode($value);
    }
    $req .= "&$key=$value";
}

if (USE_SANDBOX == true) {
    $paypal_url = "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr";
} else {
    $paypal_url = "https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr";
}

$ch = curl_init($paypal_url);

if ($ch == false) {
    return false;
}

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $req);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, 1);

if (DEBUG == true) {
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, 1);
}

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Connection: Close'));

$res = curl_exec($ch);

if (curl_errno($ch) != 0) // cURL error
{
    if (DEBUG == true) {
        error_log(date('[Y-m-d H:i e] ') . "No se puede conectar a PayPal para validar el IPN: " . curl_error($ch) . PHP_EOL, 3, LOG_FILE);
    }
    curl_close($ch);
    exit;
} else {
    if (DEBUG == true) {
        error_log(date('[Y-m-d H:i e] ') . "HTTP respuesta:" . curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT) . " para IPN: $req" . PHP_EOL, 3, LOG_FILE);
        error_log(date('[Y-m-d H:i e] ') . "HTTP respuesta a la validacion: $res" . PHP_EOL, 3, LOG_FILE);
    }
    curl_close($ch);
}

$tokens = explode("\r\n\r\n", trim($res));
$res    = trim(end($tokens));

if (strcmp($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) {

    $txt = fopen("paypalpagos.txt", "a+");

    ob_start();
    var_dump($_POST);
    $result = ob_get_clean();

    fputs($txt, $result);
    @fclose($fp);

    if (DEBUG == true) {
        error_log(date('[Y-m-d H:i e] ') . "IPN Verificado: $req " . PHP_EOL, 3, LOG_FILE);
    }
} else if (strcmp($res, "INVALID") == 0) {
    if (DEBUG == true) {
        error_log(date('[Y-m-d H:i e] ') . "IPN Invalido: $req" . PHP_EOL, 3, LOG_FILE);
    }
}
```

si me funciona, así que debe algo que hago mal en la redacción del código al formato laravel o cuando pasa por el request.

Comment: ¿qué es lo que no funciona exactamente? ¿algún mensaje de error?

Comment: si no logra funcionar, como que no pasa los datos por el route y el request. al final el ipn hice toda la lógica con php puro. pero quisiera que estuviera dentro de un controlador laravel, pero me rendí. si quisieras ayudarme seria de gran ayuda para aprender.